# First time chilly grower! Advice and tips?

Tags: chili

This is my first time growing anything so I decided I'll start with something that I really like to eat as well.

These are Apache chillies. Germinated my seeds in a propagator, in peats, temperature around 22-26 Celsius. Watered them enough to keep them wet. Once they sprouted and the root started showing at the bottom of the peat I transplanted the first two. The rest are still not showing the root. Used pre-fertilised potting soil. Should be well airated and the little pots (7cm) have holes in the bottom for draining.

They are growing at a window still with about 11 hours of light each day, some direct sunlight around the noon/afternoon. They are 10 days old at the moment (since I sawed the seeds).

Firstly I just wanted to ask if they are looking ok, never grown anything before so I'm not sure if the seedlings look too leggy or not, and what should I be careful about going forward. How long until the next, true leaves appear? Any tips/advice very welcome.

Let me know if more pictures are needed.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think it is best to ask direct questions. It is difficult to answer generic questions/comments. Your chili seems good, I think you transplanted to early (I would always wait few leaves).

Comment: Apologies and thanks for the reply! I guess my two questions were if the seedlings were looking too leggy and how long do they usually take until the next few leaves appear? Is that something dependent on the variety?